# Change the speed of another application

Tags: c++, windows

I'll be very specific about this, this is a real question and I'm facing a real problem right now.

I don't want to optimize my program, or my code, in order to make it run faster, its not that.
I must write a program that changes the 'speed' of another program.

An example for this is CE 'speedhack', you select a target program and makes it run faster or slower, if you're playing a flash game in a browser you can slow down the flash plugin speed which makes the game run 'faster' or 'slower'.

[image]

I know that CE does this loading a library into the other program and most certainly the library creates a thread at `DllMain`, `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` which will change the 'speed' of other threads in the program. So it doesn't even gets to be 'other' application at that case.

All I want is the right direction for this, how is this 'speed' changed.
Please do not close my question, if you did not understand please leave a comment I'll provide necessary details. I'm a real programmer looking for a real answer.

Comment: `I'm a real programmer looking for a real answer` Had to laugh :D

Comment: You asked the same question like 10 minutes ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speed up another application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671718/speed-up-another-application)

Comment: I cannot delete it, I've asked to, this might silly as it is, but it's what I need

Comment: Are you looking for a platform independent solution or just for Windows?

Comment: (This is merely my speculation. I have no evidence at all.) In most program, delay() is used to control the frame rate. Cheat Engine might reduce the duration of delay() to change the speed of the program.

Comment: Have you read the wiki: http://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Cheat_Engine:Internals#Speedhack

Comment: What I understood is that it is hooking `GetTickCount()` and returning its own value, is that right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this "speedhack" doesn't *actually* make a program run faster. It just manipulates the timers the program uses by hooking (via dll-injection). Just like the values that Java's `System.currentTimeMillis()` or C++'s `time_t  time; time(&time)` give. 
A more detailed explanation can be found at [Cheat Engine internals](http://wiki.cheatengine.org/index.php?title=Cheat_Engine%3aInternals#Speedhack).

The formula then is `returned_time = basetime+((currenttime-basetime)*speed_factor)`.

Comment: I should have posted my comment as an answer. :(

Comment: (And since the timer involves in the gameplay and rendering, it makes the game appears to be faster or slower).

Comment: Oh I definitely understood it this time. It's hooking timer functions calls and returning a modified value. Would never think that would work. Thank you